# How do I call a subclass in an API result?

Tags: macos, swift

When I am trying to call an API in swift, how can I access the subclass?

```
{
    "country": {
        "bar": "australia",
        "bar2": "melbourne"
    },

}
```

I know with regular API calls you use `jsonResult["country"] as AnyObject? as? String` however I am getting nil when doing that because I assume I am not calling "bar", just "country" which contains both "bar" and "bar2".

What is the syntax to do this? I have tried `["country"]["bar"], ["country.bar"]` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Then you may use it like this:

```
if let bar = jsonResult["country"]["bar"].string{
    // get bar now
} else {
    // no result
}
```

BTW, if you tend to use default Swift library, you may do like this:

```
if let country = jsonResult["country"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
    if let bar = country["bar"] as? String {
        // get bar now
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! Besides clean code, is there any advantage to using SwiftyJSON?

Comment: You can refer to the docs of SwiftyJSON. Handling JSON becomes much easier in Swift with SwiftyJSON. It provides with useful optional and error handling. And the biggest advantage is making your code clean.